# Importing data from svg website with excel vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, svg

Hi everyone im trying to import a table from a website that I think is SVG.

The table I'm trying to import is this one http://clubelo.com/2018-02-11/Results

All I have is a basic code to import text from a regular website, I'm very new to VBA.

Can anyone help me with a VBA script to import this data to excel.

Comment: Go to [http://api.clubelo.com/2018-02-11](http://api.clubelo.com/2018-02-11) and you can get the data in **csv** format, ready to be imported in Excel.

Comment: Sorry. The data in the api is different. It is the ranking, not the results.

Comment: If you do that you will see that you are not importing the table, i´ve done that. you are only importing the left column of the site.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Sorry. My mistake.

Comment: No problem. I´am crazy about this sit,e because i can´t understand how to import that table.....

Answer (score 0):

*This Code will import Table from the Web link.*

```
    Sub Import_SVGTabledata()

    Dim url As String, links_count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, row As Integer
    Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object
    Dim tr_coll As Object, tr As Object
    Dim td_coll As Object, td As Object

    links_count = 1
    For i = 0 To links_count

        url = "Type Your Link Here" & i & ".html"

        Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
        XMLHTTP.send

        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.ResponseText

        Set tbl = html.getelementsbytagname("Table")

        Set tr_coll = tbl(0).getelementsbytagname("TR")

        For Each tr In tr_coll
            j = 1
            Set td_col = tr.getelementsbytagname("TD")

            For Each td In td_col
                Cells(row + 1, j).Value = td.innerText
                j = j + 1
            Next
            row = row + 1
        Next
    Next

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

**NB:** You can replace the **LINK COUNT** with your value and for **URL** type the link you want to use.

*I hope this help you, since it's a tested code.*

Comment: It doesn´t work for this site, but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Nice to hear from you, @NunoCoelho, which site you have used !